# Open a basic auth dialog with only JavaScript

Tags: javascript, authentication, service-worker

I want to open this dialog with only JavaScript (controlling only the http response body, not the headers).

[image: basic auth popup]

I tried registering a service worker, and making a response with the [WWW-Authenticate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate) header, with no success.

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js', {scope: '/'});
```

sw.js

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', e => {
    e.respondWith(new Response('401', {status: 401, headers: {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic'}}));
});
```

The 401 page with the specified header shows up on the next request, but the dialog doesn't pop up.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Or is it even possible to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? These dialogs are *extremely* annoying and should have been excised from browsers 20 years ago but for legacy considerations.

Comment: Just as a proof of concept. I want to know if I could do that.

Comment: I believe this trips when the page is loaded based on the HTTP response code. In JavaScript you could redirect to a page that does, but otherwise, no. Of course, this is if you have no respect for your users and want to make their life miserable, but I digress. Please don't. Just be normal and use a regular HTML-based login form.

Comment: OK, I get it, so it is impossible, and that's it? I can do this only if I can send that header from the server. Am I correct?

Comment: That's my understanding.